# Django template FOO_set.all returns blank

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to display the value of the model **Enigme** related by a ForeignKey on the model **Salle**.

These are the classes :

```
class Escape(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Salle(models.Model):
    salle = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    escape = models.ForeignKey(Escape, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.salle


class Enigme(models.Model):
    enigme_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    salle = models.ForeignKey(Salle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.enigme_name
```

My view file :

```
def salle_escape(request):
    escape_named = 'Test'
    list_salle = Salle.objects.filter(escape__name=escape_named)
    context = { 
            'escape' : Escape.objects.get(name=escape_named),
            'salle'  : list_salle,
            }

    return render(request, 'chat/salle_escape.html', context)
```

This is my template file :

```
<!-- chat/templates/chat/room.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h2>Liste des salles</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for s in salle %}
        <li>{{ s.salle }} </li>
        <ul>
            {% for enigme in s.enigme_set.all %}
            <li>{{ engime.enigme_name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm getting, it is empty bullets :
[image]

Would you have an idea about my issue ?

Comment: Does your `Enigme` objects have an `enigme_name` that is not the empty string?

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, I can confirm you is not empty. If I try in the python shell, the enigme_names appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for enigme in s.enigme_set.all %}
    <li>{{ engime.enigme_name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

enigme != engime

you incorrectly wrote the name of the object

Comment: YOU-ARE-THE-BEST !! And shame on me .... Thank you really much, several hours I'm looking for the issue. Thanks a lot !